# Summing over unknown number of fields

Tags: mysql

`SELECT *` lets me select all fields of a given table. I use it when I don't know the names of all or the fields, or when I don't want to fix the query in question (to allow flexibility with respect to table alters).

`SELECT SUM(col)` lets me calculate the sum of a specific column in a table, whose field name I know.

Can I somehow combine the two?

For example, if `SELECT * FROM TestTable` returns the following:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |
|    2 |    3 |    4 |
|    3 |    4 |    5 |
+------+------+------+
```

Then I wish to get the following output:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| SUM(col1) | SUM(col2) | SUM(col3) |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         6 |         9 |        12 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Without using the field names `col1`, `col2` or `col3` in the query (of course, the header row can be anything else). Something like `SELECT SUM(*)` -- but that will raise a syntax error.

Perhaps I can use the information schema for that somehow? Or is there a simpler method?

Comment: How come you do not know the names of the columns? If you can find out then you have your answer as you will know the names of the columns to put into the query?

Comment: I guess you _may_ be able to solve it using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, but it would be a non portable hack. I think you're probably better off rethinking the database schema as for example altering the table to `(columnName VARCHAR(xxx), value INT)` which would give you a chance to either do `SUM(value) WHERE columnName='col1'` for a single column or `SUM(value)` for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use information schema for that. That said, even if something is possible it doesn't mean it'd be a good idea.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE colsum( tbl char(32))
BEGIN
DECLARE cur1_eof INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cname CHAR(128);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=database() AND table_name=tbl AND data_type="int";
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET cur1_eof = TRUE;

SELECT '' INTO @qs;

OPEN cur1;

cols: LOOP
 FETCH cur1 INTO cname;
 IF cur1_eof THEN
  LEAVE cols;
 END IF;
 SELECT CONCAT(@qs,IF(length(@qs)>0,',',''),'SUM(',cname,') AS ',cname) INTO @qs;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',@qs,' FROM ',tbl,';') INTO @qs;

PREPARE s1 FROM @qs;
EXECUTE s1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;

END
$$
delimiter ;
```

You can then use `call colsum('your_table');` to get the expected column sums. Example above lists only columns which are of type `INT`. It's fairly straightforward to change it to handle other column types.